Use one angular signal store for multiple features (components)
I've defined angular signal store in parent table component and update data using
patchState

export const TableStore = signalStore(
  { providedIn: 'root' },
  withRouteParams({ id: param => Number(param) }),
  withState(tableInitialState),
  withMethods((store, tableApiService = inject(TableApiService)) => ({
    getRows: rxMethod<number>(
      pipe(
        switchMap(structureId => {
          patchState(store, { loading: true });
          return tableApiService.getData(id).pipe(
            tap({
              next: (data: any) =>
                patchState(store, {
                  rows: data.rows,
                }),
              error: () =>
                patchState(store, {
                  rows: tableInitialState.rows,
                  loading: false,
                }),
              finalize: () => patchState(store, { loading: false }),
            })
          );
        })
      )
    ),
    addRow: rxMethod<Row>(...)
    ),
  })),

Code above works as expected and rows can be accessed via
store.rows()

Within the table there is an edit action which opens dialog component for the clicked row. In the dialog component I'm trying to get those rows from the same signal store;
export class DialogComponent {
   tableStore = inject(TableStore);

   ngOnInit() {
     console.log(this.tableStore.rows()); <== EMPTY ARRAY??
   }
}

but there are no data.
Does anyone know why? I've imagined table signal store to be domain level store and it's state could be used by several features at the same domain.
I've tried to get data from the table store in dialog component and create another dialog store in order to inject table store and get data from there but rows are empty as well.
export const DialogStore = signalStore(
  withMethods(
    (
      dialogStore,
      tableStore = inject(TableStore),
      tableApiService = inject(TableApiService)
    ) => ({
     updateRow: rxMethod<Row>(
        pipe(
          switchMap(updatedRow => {
            patchState(tableStore, { loading: true });
            return tableApiService
              .updateRow(updatedRow.id, updatedRow )
              .pipe(
                tapResponse({
                  next: () => {
                    console.log(tableStore.rows()), <= EMPTY ARRAY
                      patchState(tableStore, {
                        rows: tableStore
                          .rows()
                          .map(row =>
                            row.rowId === updatedRow.rowId
                              ? { ...row }
                              : row
                          ),
                      });
                    console.log(tableStore.rows()); <= EMPTY ARRAY
                  },
              );
          })
        )
      ),
})


It seems you have stated your TableStore in one's or multiple's component providers: [] section. Because of this there are multiple independent instances of TableStore across the application.
considering that you are using { providedIn: 'root' }, you can just remove it from all of providers arrays and it should then work

When removing TableStore from providers array, method getRows isn't being executed, although there is an method call  constructor() {     super();     this.tableStore.getRows(id);   }

are there any errors in the console?

No errors in the console, method just isn't being called for some reason.

Move getRows to withHooks() instead of withMethods(). there is onInit() hook which will be executed on store injection.

@SerhiiZhydetskyi what if I inject the store in many places? will it trigger onInit multiple times or it works like singleton ?
